# What pattern is this in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm seeing these sort of code in recent days:

```
<Base>
  {({ baseuri }) => (
    <Location>
      {({ navigate, location }) => {
        . . . . 
      }}
    </Location>
  )}
</Base>
```

Looking at the body of the `Base`, looks the code expects a functions which receives the argument which has `baseuri`. I'm not sure how one can implement the same. Also not sure what problem does it actually solves? Is there a name for this pattern?

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a render-props pattern and it's actually explained in the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html). Your component could be implemented like so:

```
const Base = props => (
  <article>
    <header>
      <h1>heading here</h1>
    </header>
    // treat "children" prop as a function and pass an object to it
    {props.children({
      baseuri: "https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html"
    })}
  </article>
);

const SpecificComponent = () => (
  <Base>
    // we know that "children" is expected to be a function which will receive an object as an argument. We also use destructuring to get variable from this object
    {({ baseuri }) => (
      <p>{baseuri}</p>
    )}
  </Base>
);
```

In other words, `SpecificComponent` could say to `Base` component: **"you give me the data and I tell you what to render"**.